# Getting error while testing AWS Lambda function: "Invalid database identifier"

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-rds, amazon-sns, aws-step-functions

Hi I'm getting error while testing lambda function like:

```
{
  "errorMessage": "An error occurred (InvalidParameterValue) when calling the DescribeDBInstances operation: Invalid database identifier:  &lt;RDS instance id&gt;",
  "errorType": "ClientError",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line 25, in lambda_handler\n    db_instances = rdsClient.describe_db_instances(DBInstanceIdentifier=rdsInstanceId)['DBInstances']\n",
    "  File \"/var/runtime/botocore/client.py\", line 391, in _api_call\n    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)\n",
    "  File \"/var/runtime/botocore/client.py\", line 719, in _make_api_call\n    raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)\n"
  ]
}
```

AND here is my lambda code :

```py
import json
import boto3
import logging
import os

#Logging
LOGGER = logging.getLogger()
LOGGER.setLevel(logging.INFO)

#Initialise Boto3 for RDS
rdsClient = boto3.client('rds')

def lambda_handler(event, context):

    #log input event
    LOGGER.info("RdsAutoRestart Event Received, now checking if event is eligible. Event Details ==> ", event)

    #Input event from the SNS topic originated from RDS event notifications
    snsMessage = json.loads(event['Records'][0]['Sns']['Message'])
    rdsInstanceId = snsMessage['Source ID']
    stepFunctionInput = {"rdsInstanceId": rdsInstanceId}
    rdsEventId = snsMessage['Event ID']

    #Retrieve RDS instance ARN
    db_instances = rdsClient.describe_db_instances(DBInstanceIdentifier=rdsInstanceId)['DBInstances']
    db_instance = db_instances[0]
    rdsInstanceArn = db_instance['DBInstanceArn']

    # Filter on the Auto Restart RDS Event. Event code: RDS-EVENT-0154. 

    if 'RDS-EVENT-0154' in rdsEventId:

        #log input event
        LOGGER.info("RdsAutoRestart Event detected, now verifying that instance was tagged with auto-restart-protection == yes")

        #Verify that instance is tagged with auto-restart-protection tag. The tag is used to classify instances that are required to be terminated once started. 

        tagCheckPass = 'false'
        rdsInstanceTags = rdsClient.list_tags_for_resource(ResourceName=rdsInstanceArn)
        for rdsInstanceTag in rdsInstanceTags["TagList"]:
            if 'auto-restart-protection' in rdsInstanceTag["Key"]:
                if 'yes' in rdsInstanceTag["Value"]:
                    tagCheckPass = 'true'
                    #log instance tags
                    LOGGER.info("RdsAutoRestart verified that the instance is tagged auto-restart-protection = yes, now starting the Step Functions Flow")
                else:
                    tagCheckPass = 'false'


        #log instance tags
        LOGGER.info("RdsAutoRestart Event detected, now verifying that instance was tagged with auto-restart-protection == yes")

        if 'true' in tagCheckPass:

            #Initialise StepFunctions Client
            stepFunctionsClient = boto3.client('stepfunctions')

            # Start StepFunctions WorkFlow
            # StepFunctionsArn is stored in an environment variable
            stepFunctionsArn = os.environ['STEPFUNCTION_ARN']
            stepFunctionsResponse = stepFunctionsClient.start_execution(
            stateMachineArn= stepFunctionsArn,
            name=event['Records'][0]['Sns']['MessageId'],
            input= json.dumps(stepFunctionInput)

        )

    else:

        LOGGER.info("RdsAutoRestart Event detected, and event is not eligible")

    return {
            'statusCode': 200
        }
```

I'm trying to Stop an Amazon RDS database which starts automatically after 7 days. I'm following this AWS document: [Field Notes: Stopping an Automatically Started Database Instance with Amazon RDS | AWS Architecture Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/architecture/field-notes-stopping-an-automatically-started-database-instance-with-amazon-rds/)

Can anyone help me?

Comment: I have used above document

Answer (score 1):

The error message is saying: `Invalid database identifier:  &lt;RDS instance id&gt;"`

It seems to be coming from this line:

```
db_instances = rdsClient.describe_db_instances(DBInstanceIdentifier=rdsInstanceId)['DBInstances']
```

The error message is saying that the `rdsInstanceId` variable contains `<RDS instance id>`, which seems to be an example value rather than a real value.

In looking at the code on [Field Notes: Stopping an Automatically Started Database Instance with Amazon RDS | AWS Architecture Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/architecture/field-notes-stopping-an-automatically-started-database-instance-with-amazon-rds/), it is asking you to **create a test event** that includes this message:

```
"Message": "{\"Event Source\":\"db-instance\",\"Event Time\":\"2020-07-09 15:15:03.031\",\"Identifier Link\":\"https://console.aws.amazon.com/rds/home?region=<region>#dbinstance:id=<RDS instance id>\",\"Source ID\":\"<RDS instance id>\",\"Event ID\":\"http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_Events.html#RDS-EVENT-0154\",\"Event Message\":\"DB instance started\"}",
```

If you look closely at that line, it includes this part to identify the Amazon RDS instance:

```
dbinstance:id=<RDS instance id>
```

I think that you are expected to **modify the provided test event** to fill-in your own values for anything in `<angled brackets>` (such as the Instance Id of your Amazon RDS instance).

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. When I tried to test this solution everything worked fine. In step function ,After start execution, task are repeated as expected so want to know that do i need to keep this execution running ?

Comment: When i aborted execution and again tested it . Then showed error saying state machine already exist. My concern is if i need to start step function continuously then how much bill it will incur.

Comment: Probably very little: [AWS Step Functions Pricing | Amazon Web Services](https://aws.amazon.com/step-functions/pricing/)

Comment: So I need to keep state machine running continuously ....isn't it ?

Comment: @pranavbabras Based on the diagram shown on that blog, the State Machine would end once the RDS instance is stopped. Regardless, Step Functions is only charged at state transitions, so there would be no charge if it is 'waiting' for something to occur.